# Why XPath does not work with xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xsd

I have the following XPath expression:

```xml
/configuration/properties
```

And this is my XML:

```xml
<configuration
    xmlns="http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD">
    <properties>
        <property key="a" value="1" />
        <property key="b" value="2" />
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

The XPath does not work. However If I change the name space from `xmlns` to `xmlns:conf` it works:

```xml
<configuration
    xmlns:conf="http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD">
    <properties>
        <property key="a" value="1" />
        <property key="b" value="2" />
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Search this site for "XPath default namespace" and you will get 1030 answers to your question, nearly all of them correct.

Comment: @MichaelKay You're right. But for that one should know what to search for (And I'm not the author of Author of `XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference`) :)

Comment: Yes, finding the right search terms is difficult, especially for people who haven't learnt the terminology. However, the title you chose for your question is good enough to get 223 hits.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Placing `xmlns="http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD"` on the root element** of your XML puts the root and its descendants in the `http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD` namespace.  This effectively means that all of the element names in your XML document are preceded by `http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD`.  Yet, the elements stated in your XPath are *not* in the `http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD` namespace.  Thus, your XPath **matches nothing**.

**Placing `xmlns:conf="http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD"` instead on the root element** merely defines a prefix for the `http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD` namespace but doesn't actually use it.  The root element and its descendants remain in no namespace and are therefore able to be found by your XPath that also tests in no namespace.  Thus, your XPath **matches something**.

See also **[How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)**

Answer (score 8):

That is because you are in a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.ksharma.in/myXSD"`. You can try

```
/*[local-name()='configuration']/*[local-name()='properties']
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Namespace wihtout prefix is a default namespace. Having default namespace, XML element where the namespace is declared and it's descendants without prefix and without different non-prefixed namespace declaration considered in the same namespace.

The second XML above has namespace declaration with prefix. In this case, for an element to be considered in that prefixed-namespace it has to be declared explicitly using corresponding prefix.

To be able to access elements in default namespace you have to declare a prefix that point to default namespace URI and use that prefix in your XPath query (or ignore the namespace by using `local-name()` as suggested in @Joel's answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Check this article](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/namespace-wildcards-in-xpath/).

Change your xpath config to `/\*:configuration/\*:properties` and you should be good to go.