# Using XPath to get an element in SVG

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I am trying to get an element in an SVG file using XPath. I have tried the following code, but `singleNodeValue` is null. The `doc` seems to be correct, so I guess either `evaluate()` arguments or the XPath is wrong, but I cannot find anything wrong. Why doesn't it work?

JavaScript

```
fetch('test.svg')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data=>{
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
    console.log(doc);
    const res = doc.evaluate("//symbol[@label='square']", doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
    console.log(res.singleNodeValue);
})
```

SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <symbol label ="square">
        <rect y="5" x="5" width="90" height="90" stroke-width="5" stroke="#f00" fill="#f00" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </symbol>

</svg>
```

---

After some testing, I have discovered that it works if I remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. I searched the web and found an answer: [Why XPath does not work with xmlns attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492186/why-xpath-does-not-work-with-xmlns-attribute)

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of the extracting the tag?

Comment: @Dementic To display only selected image when an SVG contains multiple images. The SVG in the question is for illustration only; not the real SVG which I am trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol label ="square"><rect y="5" x="5" width="90" height="90" stroke-width="5" stroke="#f00" fill="#f00" fill-opacity="0.5" /></symbol></svg>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");

const res = doc.querySelector("symbol[label=square]");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What you used is the thing called CSS selector, right? So, I must use CSS selector, not Xpath?

Comment: querySelector is a javascript selector (Tag and attribute with specific value).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Since your document is now parsed, you can use any JS method to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a namespace resolver in XPath 1 and with the `evaluate` function and even of an XPath default namespace in XPath 2 and later such as supported by Saxon-JS 2:

```js
const svgString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:dog = "http://dog.com/dog">

    <symbol dog:label="square">
        <rect y="5" x="5" width="90" height="90" stroke-width="5" stroke="#f00" fill="#f00" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol dog:label="cat">
        <rect y="5" x="5" width="90" height="90" stroke-width="5" stroke="#f00" fill="#f00" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </symbol>
</svg>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgString, 'application/xml');

const result = doc.evaluate(`//svg:symbol[@dog:label='cat']`, doc, function(prefix) { if (prefix === 'svg') return 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'; else if (prefix === 'dog') return 'http://dog.com/dog'; else return null; }, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

console.log(result.singleNodeValue);


const result2 = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`//symbol[@dog:label = 'cat']`, doc, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', namespaceContext : { 'dog' : 'http://dog.com/dog' } });

console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```